# If Pell's equation $x^2-Dy^2=-1$ has a solution, then $D$ is the sum of two relatively prime squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the equation $x^2-Dy^2=-1$ has a solution only if $D$ is not divisible by 4, and also cannot be divisible by any prime of the form $4k+3$. Conclude from this that $D$ is representable as $u^2+v^2$ where $(u,v)=1$.

I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Do you know the theorems that (1) $\;x^2=-1\pmod p\;$ is solvable iff $\;p=1\pmod 4\;$ , and (2) a natural number is the sum of two squares iff any prime divisor of it that is equal to $\;3\pmod 4\;$ divides the number at an even exponent?

Comment: Oh, yes I recall the first one. The second one looks kind of familiar. Thank you!

Comment: Good @Hershey, so there you go...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $D$ is divisible by some prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$. If $x^2-Dy^2=-1$, then $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. It is a standard result that this is impossible if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$, since for such primes $-1$ is not a QR of $p$.

If $D$ is divisible by $4$, we would have $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. This is impossible, since any odd square is in fact congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.

The representability of such $D$ as a sum of two relatively prime squares is a standard theorem.

Comment: Hm, but it seems like the question wants you to use the first part to conclude that $D$ can be written as the sum of 2 (coprime) squares.